# CascadeClassifier error with Right path of file OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

This is my Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time
muka = cv2.CascadeClassifier.load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
print(muka.empty())
while True:
    #Capture frameByFrame
    check, frame = video.read()
    #Display Hasil frame dalam gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mukaku = muka.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in mukaku:
        Rgray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        Rcolor = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        imgItem = "muka.png"
        cv2.imwrite(imgItem, Rgray)
        color = (0, 200, 200) #warna BGR
        tebal = 2 #tebal garis
        lebar = x + w #Kordinat x
        tinggi = y + h #Kordinat Y
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (lebar, tinggi), color, tebal)
    cv2.imshow('Rekam', gray)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have this error message :

**muka = cv2.CascadeClassifier.load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
TypeError: descriptor 'load' for 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
PS C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts>**

Comment: I've been try use specific path "C:/blabla/blabla" but Have the same error

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857908/face-detection-using-cascade-classifier-in-opencv-python#30860506 -- it seems like you might need to fully specify the path, using backslashes instead of slashed.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495524/13036351) this work for me Thank You!

Comment: Amazing! Good luck with the rest, and welcome to Stack Overflow ;)