# I could use some help - OpenCV is giving me a hard time

Tags: python, opencv

So I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/matt/Dropbox/HumanPiano/Test/Test_1.py", line 17, in 
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0)
> /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-gi6lxw0x/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'

And am trying to run the example code:

```
import cv2  
  
# Load the cascade  
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')  
  
# To capture video from webcam.   
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
  
while True:  
    # Read the frame  
    _, img = cap.read()  
  
    # Convert to grayscale  
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
  
    # Detect the faces  
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)  
  
    # Draw the rectangle around each face  
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)  
  
    # Display  
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)  
  
    # Stop if escape key is pressed  
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff  
    if k==27:  
        break  
          
# Release the VideoCapture object  
cap.release()
```

How do I fix/address it?

Comment: Give the correct path of .xml file

Comment: also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857908/face-detection-throws-error-empty-in-function-cvcascadeclassifierdetectm?rq=1

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you haven't searched for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add this before referring to the path of .xml.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Hope this would solve your problem.